# Optimize Oracle query to include only one statement and make the script run faster

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I have this sequel where I'm listing all my deals, where I'm only interested in those deals that are not booked by Interface and where the Source Interface = TBG.

I want to add another statement where again I'm looking only at deals not booked by Interface but this time interested in another field called System Booking ID which should always have entries in it. These two fields should be tested as OR conditions not AND.

I below listed the initial statement and then modified this to create another one which fulfills the conditions for 'System Booking ID' IS NOT NULL.

If I run these together, they seem to work. However, the script now takes much longer to complete.
Is there I way where I can add these additional conditions to the first statement, instead of creating a whole new one? I guess that would make it run faster.

----initial statement

```
SELECT ab.deal_num
                FROM history_table abh
                INNER JOIN deal_table ab ON (
                        abh.tran_num = ab.tran_num
                        AND ab.tran_type = 0
                        )
                INNER JOIN ins i ON (
                        ab.ins_type = i.id_number
                        AND i.id_number IN (
                            605
                            ,610
                            )
                        )
                INNER JOIN personnel_table p ON (
                        abh.personnel_id = p.id_number
                        AND UPPER(p.name) NOT LIKE 'Interface%'
                        )
                INNER JOIN tran_info_types tit ON ('Source Interface' = tit.type_name)
                LEFT OUTER JOIN ab_tran_info ati ON (
                        tit.type_id = ati.type_id
                        AND ab.tran_num = ati.tran_num
                        )
                WHERE 1 = 1
                    AND abh.row_creation > TO_DATE('16-Mar-23 22:56:16', 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS') - 90
                    AND ati.value = 'TBG'
                    AND abh.version_number = 1
```

----additional statement

```
SELECT ab.deal_num
                    FROM history_table abh
                    INNER JOIN deal_table ab ON (
                            abh.tran_num = ab.tran_num
                            AND ab.tran_type = 0
                            )
                    INNER JOIN ins i ON (
                            ab.ins_type = i.id_number
                            AND i.id_number IN (
                                605
                                ,610
                                )
                            )
                    INNER JOIN personnel_table p ON (
                            abh.personnel_id = p.id_number
                            AND UPPER(p.name) NOT LIKE 'Interface%'
                            )
                    INNER JOIN tran_info_types tit ON ('System Booking ID' = tit.type_name)
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN ab_tran_info ati ON (
                            tit.type_id = ati.type_id
                            AND ab.tran_num = ati.tran_num
                            )
                    WHERE 1 = 1
                        AND abh.row_creation > TO_DATE('16-Mar-23 22:56:16', 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS') - 90
                        AND ati.value IS NOT NULL
                        AND abh.version_number = 1
```

Even if I run just this part of the sequel, it still returns deals booked with 'INTERFACE'

```
      SELECT ab.deal_num
            FROM history_table abh
            INNER JOIN deal_table ab ON (
                    abh.tran_num = ab.tran_num
                    AND ab.tran_type = 0
                    )
            INNER JOIN ins i ON (
                    ab.ins_type = i.id_number
                    AND i.id_number IN (
                        605
                        ,610
                        )
                    )
            INNER JOIN personnel_table p ON (
                    abh.personnel_id = p.id_number
                    AND UPPER(p.name) NOT LIKE 'INTERFACE%'
                    )
            LEFT OUTER JOIN ab_tran_info ati ON (
                    ab.tran_num = ati.tran_num
                    )
            LEFT OUTER JOIN tran_info_types tit ON (
                    tit.type_id = ati.type_id
                    )
            WHERE rownum <1000
```

I think I identified the line where it stops excluding deals with 'INTERFACE'. It must be something with adding these two fields that the sequel doesn't like.

```
    SELECT ab.deal_num
            FROM history_table abh
            INNER JOIN deal_table ab ON (
                    abh.tran_num = ab.tran_num
                    AND ab.tran_type = 0
                    )
            INNER JOIN ins i ON (
                    ab.ins_type = i.id_number
                    AND i.id_number IN (
                        605
                        ,610
                        )
                    )
            INNER JOIN personnel_table p ON (
                    abh.personnel_id = p.id_number
                    AND UPPER(p.name) NOT LIKE 'INTERFACE%'
                    )
            LEFT OUTER JOIN ab_tran_info ati ON (
                    ab.tran_num = ati.tran_num
                    )
            LEFT OUTER JOIN tran_info_types tit ON (
                    tit.type_id = ati.type_id
                    )
            WHERE 1 = 1
                AND abh.row_creation > TO_DATE('16-Mar-23 22:56:16', 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS') - 90
                AND abh.version_number = 1
```

Comment: please take a look at the tag description of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query-optimization (under learn more)  and add the missing information

Answer (score 0):

To me, it seems that this line:

```
INNER JOIN tran_info_types tit ON ('System Booking ID' = tit.type_name)
```

should be moved into `WHERE` clause (that's just a condition which filters rows on `type_name`), while `JOIN` itself also looks differently. Something like this:

```
              SELECT ab.deal_num
                FROM history_table abh
                INNER JOIN deal_table ab ON (
                        abh.tran_num = ab.tran_num
                        AND ab.tran_type = 0
                        )
                INNER JOIN ins i ON (
                        ab.ins_type = i.id_number
                        AND i.id_number IN (
                            605
                            ,610
                            )
                        )
                INNER JOIN personnel_table p ON (
                        abh.personnel_id = p.id_number
                        AND UPPER(p.name) NOT LIKE 'Interface%'
                        )
                LEFT OUTER JOIN ab_tran_info ati ON (
                        ab.tran_num = ati.tran_num
                        )
                LEFT OUTER JOIN tran_info_types tit ON (
                        tit.type_id = ati.type_id
                        )
                WHERE 1 = 1
                    AND abh.row_creation > TO_DATE('16-Mar-23 22:56:16', 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS') - 90
                    AND abh.version_number = 1
                    AND ( (     tit.type_name = 'System Booking ID' 
                            AND ati.value IS NOT NULL
                           )
                        OR (     tit.type_name = 'System Source Interface' 
                            AND ati.value = 'TBG'
                           )
```

---

As of performance: for start, I'd make sure that columns used in joins and filters are indexed, tables and indexes *analyzed* (statistics gathered) and let optimizer do what it can. If that's not good enough, then look at performance tuning.

Comment: I'm looking for deals where tit.type_name = 'System Booking ID' OR tit.type_name = 'System Source Interface'

Comment: I need to test for both conditions as OR statements.

Comment: That's just `AND tit.type_name IN ('System Source Interface', 'System Booking ID')`

Comment: What about ati.value? I I need ati.value = 'TBG' for the first field OR ati.value IS NOT NULL   for the second field...

Comment: Aha; didn't notice that difference between your two queries. Fixed; have a look, please.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. It's showing deals booked by 'Interface'.  The condition below doesn't seem to pass through the sequel:  AND UPPER(p.name) NOT LIKE 'Interface%'

Comment: Well, if there's UPPER function involved, then it should be `AND UPPER(p.name) NOT LIKE 'INTERFACE%'`

Comment: Even if I run this chunk of the code, it still returns deals booked with INTERFACE. Just added this to the end of the original post.

Comment: Is INTERFACE the 1st word in that column? Should condition have `NOT LIKE '%INTERFACE%'` (i.e. % sign at the beginning and at the end)?

Comment: Indeed, INTERFACE is the 1st word in the column. Even if I do NOT LIKE '%INTERFACE%', it still shows deals with INTERFACE.

Comment: I think I found the line until where it works OK. After adding the two fields, it starts showing deals with 'INTERFACE'. I have put the sequel in the original post.